# Karma Testing Angular Seed Project System.JS path error

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-seed

I'm just getting started with Angular using https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed as my initial setup.

I'm having some problems getting an initial unit test setup with Jasmine. The OAuth library used in my project seems to be the issue, but I'm not sure whether it can be safely suppressed or what changes I need to make to the config. The base/node_modules path is currently incorrect, but I'm not sure which part of the configuration builds this. I've tried adding the path to the ignored section but the error persists. Any help appreciated.

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Jul 15 2015 09:44:02 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
'use strict';

var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var minimatch = require("minimatch");


module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: './',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // Polyfills.
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/intl/dist/Intl.min.js',

      'node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js',

      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Zone.js dependencies
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',

      // RxJs.
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      // paths loaded via module imports
      // Angular itself
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

      { pattern: 'dist/dev/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: 'dist/dev/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true, served: true },
      { pattern: 'dist/dev/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true, served: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included: false, watched: false }, // PhantomJS2 (and possibly others) might require it

      // suppress annoying 404 warnings for resources, images, etc.
      { pattern: 'dist/dev/assets/**/*', watched: false, included: false, served: true },

      'test-config.js',
      'dist/dev/app/system-config.js',
      'test-main.js'
    ],

    // must go along with above, suppress annoying 404 warnings.
    proxies: {
      '/assets/': '/base/dist/dev/assets/'
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules/**/*spec.js',
      'node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index.js',
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['mocha'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [
      'Chrome'
    ],


    customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Passing command line arguments to tests
    client: {
      files:  argv.files ? minimatch.makeRe(argv.files).source : null
    }
  });

  if (process.env.APPVEYOR) {
    config.browsers = ['IE'];
    config.singleRun = true;
    config.browserNoActivityTimeout = 90000; // Note: default value (10000) is not enough
  }

  if (process.env.TRAVIS || process.env.CIRCLECI) {
    config.browsers = ['Chrome_travis_ci'];
    config.singleRun = true;
    config.browserNoActivityTimeout = 90000;
  }
};
```

The following is the error message :

```
06 07 2017 09:27:29.589:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://loca
lhost:9876/
06 07 2017 09:27:29.590:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited
 concurrency
06 07 2017 09:27:29.595:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
06 07 2017 09:27:31.064:INFO [Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected o
n socket /#4mhCO5mVkEwzD0EfAAAA with id 14947625
06 07 2017 09:27:32.242:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/angular-oauth
2-oidc/dist/index.js
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found
) loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index
.js
        Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/node
_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index.js
            at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (ht
tp://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b6
52319d281eef1d450d5:1056:39)
            at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/
zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:424:31)
            at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dis
t/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:191:47)
            at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/node_m
odules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:486:38)
        Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular-oauth2-oid
c/dist/index.js as "angular-oauth2-oidc" from http://localhost:9876/base/dist/de
v/app/shared/login/login-service.js'
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR: '(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found
) loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index
.js
        Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9876/base/node
_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index.js
            at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (ht
tp://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b6
52319d281eef1d450d5:1056:39)
            at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/
zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:424:31)
            at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dis
t/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:191:47)
            at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/node_m
odules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?082dc1d83c7a42ddda9b652319d281eef1d450d5:486:38)
        Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular-oauth2-oid
c/dist/index.js as "angular-oauth2-oidc" from http://localhost:9876/base/dist/de
v/app/shared/login/login-service.js'
06 07 2017 09:27:32.274:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/angular-oauth
2-oidc/dist/index.js
```

Update:

After removing the list of files to exclude:

[image]

Comment: can you show out your project structure?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to proxy node_module too

```
 proxies: {
            '/node_modules/': "/base/node_modules/",
            '/assets/': '/base/dist/dev/assets/'
        },
```

Comment: Still 404's with that unfortunately.

Comment: Also remove this from the config:                                                                 // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules/**/*spec.js',
      'node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/dist/index.js',
    ],

Comment: Looks like it is mapping to node_modules folder twice. Try removing the '/node_modules/': "/base/node_modules/" from proxies.